# PowerShell: Retrieve specific words from API response & Compile into HTML Table

Tags: powershell

I am trying to retrieve specific words from an API, unfortunately the API response is just a body response which contains the following text - example below:

> They have found that this is due to in issue with the 3rd party Studio, Square Melon, who have been contacted and are working on a solution. Updates to follow once the issue has been resolved, pending feedback from the teams.
>  Incident Commander: Barrie James 
>   Remedy INC1063757 PD 387049

What would be the best way to a retrieve "Barrie James" & and the INC Number (INC1063757). Unfortunately I have been stuck on this for a while now because there might be multiple different incidents which means that the name and INC number will change.

Any ideas?

Comment: If all you got is text, regex or convertfrom-string might work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you assign the response from this API to a variable, `$response`, we first need to break this up from one string into an array of strings, which we'll do like so.

```
 $response = Invoke-RestMethod -uri www.mycoolsite.com #or maybe Invoke-WebRequest
 $response
 >They have found that this is due to in issue with the 3rd party Studio, Square Melon, who have been contacted and are working on a solution. Updates to follow once the issue has been resolved, pending feedback from the teams.
Incident Commander: Barrie James
Remedy INC1063757 PD 387049

 $response.Count
 >1

 #we need response to be an array of strings for Select-string to work.  
 $response.Split("`n").Count
 >3
```

We called the `Split()` method on the variable `$response` and broke it up anywhere it sees the hidden `'n` PowerShell new line character.

Next, we can use the `|` pipe character to send the array of strings over to `Select-String` and look for lines with a certain string in them.

```
$response.Split("`n") | select-string "Incident Commander:"
```

That parses the results into something useful, shown below.

```
$response.Split("`n") | select-string "Incident Commander:"
IgnoreCase : True
LineNumber : 2
Line       : Incident Commander: Barrie James
Filename   : InputStream
Path       : InputStream
Pattern    : Incident Commander:
Context    : 
Matches    : {0}
```

From here, we just select the line property, which has the text `Incident Commander: Barrie James` in it.

```
($response.Split("`n") | select-string "Incident Commander:").Line
>Incident Commander: Barrie James
```

All that remains is to get rid of the colon, which we will do with the `.Split()` method. 
This will break the string into separate strings wherever it sees the character we provide.

```
($response.Split("`n") | select-string "Incident Commander:").Line.Split(":")
Incident Commander
 Barrie James
```

Now, to select just the second item, which we do with indexing.  Indexing in PowerShell starts at zero (of course), so we actually ask for 'the item at index 1', which means the second position.

```
($response.Split("`n") | select-string "Incident Commander:").Line.Split(":")[1].Trim()
Barrie James
```

And there you go.  That's how you do it and why we do each step.

Comment: wow awesome thanks so much! How am I then able to put all of that into a ForEach statement so I can get all of the responses? I then need to feed it into a HTML table row: <tr><td></td></tr>

Comment: That's a different question, because we'd need to know what the list of responses look like.  Recommend you accept this as an answer and then ask another question with specifics about what else you'd like to do.